# header() moves me automatically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "validate.php",
                    data: {password: password},
                    success:
                    function(data)
                    {
                        if(data == "1")
                        {
                            alert("password c.");
                            var header = "<?php header('Location: administration.php'); ?>";
                            alert(header);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("password - inc.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**validate.php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    if($password == "0000")
    {
        echo("1");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("0");
    }
}
```

?>

If I want to back from administration.php to index.php, function header() moves me to the index automatically. Why? How do I make a move only when my password is entered? So the password has to be entered even if I move from administration.php to index.php.

Comment: `header('Location: administration.php');` sends a header to the browser, telling it to do a redirect. It doesn't "return" anything so you can't store it in a js-variable. However, you should actually get some "headers already sent" messages here. All headers must be sent before _any_ output is made to the browser. If you want to redirect the user to some page in JS, use: `location.href = "some-page.php";` instead.

Comment: _All headers must be sent before any output is made to the browser._ - Why? I would like to just understand this problem, because it is interesting me.

Comment: When you make a http request and get a response, the headers in the response will give you information about the response. What type of response is it? How should it be handled? All that info needs to be sent to the client _before_ the actual content, or the client won't know what to do with the content when it gets it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: So, instead of loading the page, the header () function was fulfilled because there was anything in front of it. What if I called a function, that would be header () and function would be absolutely the first?